# How can I fix this issue when .appendText() "Cannot insert an empty text element"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've created this function that gets the a values from a google sheet column and appends it to a google Docs document as text and Qr code.

But I keep on getting this error(Cannot insert an empty text element. (line 54, file "Code")Dismiss) even though I get the text and the Or codes displayed in my my target document.
I assume that it has to do with the rows with no values after the last populated row.
Is there something I could do in my for loop?

```
  function createQRCodeFromColumnList() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd')// source ID
     var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('LISTS');// my source sheet
     var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
     var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow -1,1).getValues();// the row with the values 
     to become OR codes and references 
      Logger.log(sourceData);

     //target doc
     var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('3fgsdfgfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfg44');// 
     destination Doc
     var body = targetDoc.getBody();

      for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
      var sourceId = sourceData[i][0];

      var url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + sourceId

      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the image of QR code
      body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendText(sourceId);// QR Code referencence number
      body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());// OR code
      }
```

[image: Disired results]

Comment: This `sourceSheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow -1,1).getValues();` should probably be this `sourceSheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow -2,1).getValues();`

Comment: And perhaps this: `for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
  var sourceId = sourceData[i][0];
  if(sourceId) {
    var url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + sourceId
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // Get the image of QR code
    body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendText(sourceId);// QR Code referencence number
    body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());// OR code
  }
} `

Comment: Hi, I've decresed the row to - 2 and added the " if(sourceId) {" statment as suggested, but get the same error and results.  
error(Cannot insert an empty text element. (line 54, file "Code")Dismiss)

Comment: I don't see 54 lines of code

Comment: I sorry Cooper. Your suggestion works. I just had to put the rest of my code inside the if statement bracts. I would be more than happy to mark it as an answer the if you post it as such. Thank you.   for (var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) { var sourceId = sourceData[i][0];  if(sourceId) { var url ="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" + sourceId var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendText(sourceId); body.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob()); }  } }

Comment: I just have one question about Request failed for https://chart.googleapis.com returned code 502. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206550/discussion-between-user2916405-and-cooper).